# How can I take this HTML anchored element and change the text to be a FB button?

Tags: html, facebook, button

Below you can see I have an anchored element. On my webpage I can only get 'Share on Facebook' to show up. I would very much like that text on the webpage to be the Facebook share button instead. When I try putting an image in place of the text nothing happens.

I would like it to look be this image possibly.

https://paradoxonlux.deviantart.com/art/Dark-Facebook-Button-272390764

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" target="_blank">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding what I needed on the Facebook documentation page for using their 'Share button.'

It ended up working perfectly.

Here is the website I went to as well.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fbestill.getforge.io%2F&layout=button_count&size=large&mobile_iframe=true&width=84&height=28&appId" width="84" height="28" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things:
1. Use tools which Facebook has provided
2. Use image

---

**1. Use Facebook tools**
Go to [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) and choose the right option for you. You can set height, width, style and everything there.

**2. Use Image**
You can use the image you put in your question. use this:

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" target="_blank"> <img src = "https://pre00.deviantart.net/78d4/th/pre/i/2011/338/6/1/dark_facebook_button_by_paradoxonlux-d4i6a24.jpg"> </a>
```

This will act the image as a button so when you click the image, the link will be opened.

---

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it into a button and instead of href use onclick attribute.

Then style it using css